# Symfony - I want to range my datafield between dates using Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

I want to range my datafield between this dates:

```
14/01/2019 to  14/04/2019
```

And this is the code i have

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchasedate", type="datetime")
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("purchasedate")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 */
private $purchasedate;
```

Comment: What have you tried? :)

Comment: RangeField;Range , but i can make the code work

Comment: Are you asking about validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

// ...

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchasedate", type="datetime")
 * 
 * @Assert\Range(
 *      min = "2019-01-14",
 *      max = "2019-04-14"
 * )
 * 
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("purchasedate")
 * @Serializer\Expose()
 */
private $purchasedate;
```

[Constraints/Range](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html)